# PyTorch Geometric - How to sample huge graph to train GNN with mini-batching

Tags: graph, deep-learning, large-data, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I want to do node regression on a huge graph (around 1M nodes) using PyTorch Geometric, but I cannot create a `Data` object because the full graph does not fin in RAM, so I cannot use the `DataLoader` class for mini-batching and training.

Some examples (such as [4. Scaling Graph Neural Networks](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1XAjcjRHrSR_ypCk_feIWFbcBKyT4Lirs?usp=sharing)) introduce the `Clusterdata` and `ClusterLoader` classes, but this does not help my case because they can actually load the entire graph.

I have already pre-computed node embeddings and edges into separate files, which I can read very fast, to load graph subsets and the embeddings of specific nodes. However, I do not know how I should sample the graph during training, or if any existing PyTorch modules do this already.

My question is: **Are there any modules from PyTorch Geometric that can create mini batches to train my GCN without loading the entire graph in memory? If not, how should I do the graph sampling?**

In the PyTorch Geometric docs there are many examples of node and graph regression, classification... but none of the examples explain how to handle such large graphs, as they use datasets composed of many small graphs which all fit in RAM.

In another Google Colab notebook example ([2. Node Classification with Graph Neural Networks](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14OvFnAXggxB8vM4e8vSURUp1TaKnovzX?usp=sharing#scrollTo=p3TAi69zI1bO)), the entire graph from an existing dataset (Planetoid) is loaded in RAM.

```
dataset = Planetoid(root='data/Planetoid', name='Cora', transform=NormalizeFeatures())
...
data = dataset[0]  # Get the first graph object.
```

Then later, a `train` function for one training epoch of the model is defined, which uses the full `data.x` and `data.edge_index` of the graph.

```
def train():
      model.train()
      optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients.
      out = model(data.x, data.edge_index)  # Perform a single forward pass.
      loss = criterion(out[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])  # Compute the loss solely based on the training nodes.
      loss.backward()  # Derive gradients.
      optimizer.step()  # Update parameters based on gradients.
      return loss
```

From this example, I guess that each mini-batch from my graph should be created by:

1. Selecting a random subset of nodes from my graph.
2. Reading all edges and node embeddings involving the selected nodes.

And then, train one epoch on this mini-batch. However, what if none of my randomly selected nodes are adjacent, and no message passing is done? Is there a proper way to sample from this graph without this happening? For instance, could we pick one random node and then take as subset some neighborhood?

Comment: Did you solve this problem, eventually? Have you any link helpful for exploring more about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any modules from PyTorch Geometric that can create mini batches to train my GCN without loading the entire graph in memory?

Yes, by using NeighborLoaders.

If you have a graph using Data object type, you can feed it to a NeighborLoader object.

```
loader = NeighborLoader(
    data,
    # Sample 30 neighbors for each node for 2 iterations
    num_neighbors=[30] * 2,
    # Use a batch size of 128 for sampling training nodes
    batch_size=128,
    input_nodes=data.train_mask,
)
```

Comment: If the data is huge, you may not be able to have it in a single pytorch geometric data object and load it into memory. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user85361 Like normal machine learning, sometimes you cannot feed the whole dataset into memory. So you do mini-batching. However, note that this type of mini-batching is different from that of ML or DL on tabular data. Typically, graph data is non i.i.d, so mini-batching is done by taking the mini-batch nodes AND their neighbors through l layers, so that the message-passing phase is done without any error.